# Is there a naming guideline for iterator variables where the singular form is the same as the plural form?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, naming-conventions

In .NET there is a common accepted and widely adopted naming convention. For example I found this [Blogpost](http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices) very useful, it describes in detail which naming convention the internal framework code and it's external API follow. For example `int _myPrivateIntVariable` for private class-level variables of different cases (camel case, pascal case) for other code parts. According to this convention, variables on the procedure level would be camel case, e.g. `int myIntVariable`.

So according to this, when I'm iterating through a collection of objects I have the collection named in a plural form (`items`) whereas the current variable in the iteration is named according to the objects singular form (`item`).

Sometimes I'm dealing with objects where the noun describing my objects has only one form that is used for singular and plural (this happens to me more often when dealing with German words but we also could have this with English words).

So suppose we have the following code:

```
var sheep = new List<Sheep>();
// Adding objects to the collection

foreach (var sheep in sheep)
{
    // Do something with the current sheep
}
```

This code obviously won't compile because of the naming collision of the current `sheep` of the loop and the `sheep` collection.

So is there any best-practice for these kind of occasions where the resulting name wouldn't look odd/ugly?
One solution would be to prefix the variable name with an underscore but this would collide with the convention for private class-level members.
Currently, most of the time where I stumbled upon this I add an "S" to the **s**ingular variable, so for this example it would be: `foreach (var sheepS in sheep)`.
Are there any better options?

Comment: `var sheep = new List<Sheep>();` could be renamed as `var sheepCollection`... just an idea

Comment: If the entire for loop spans only a few lines, I generally use a one-letter iterator name: `foreach(var s in sheep)`. Otherwise you could just pick a generic iterator name, `item`, `instance`, etc.

Comment: The compiler does not enforce spell checking on variables.  Sheeps

Comment: Somewhat offtopic, but maybe you should use English instead of German as your keywords. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/the-ugly-american-programmer.html

Comment: @TimS.: In my programs I'm dealing with very domain-specific words where it would decrease the readability of our code when the words would be translated. Otherwise I use english words where ever possible.

Comment: @Blam: Yes that's right, there is no spell checking, some self constructed singular/plural forms just sound strange when you read them. I guess that's not the case for my sheep example, but for other words that may be a "problem".

Comment: It is a program not a short story and it is a collection not a plural.

Comment: @Blam: Well, that can't be denied...

Comment: Isn't a group of sheep called a herd? Sometime I use "current" as in foreach (var curItem in items)

Comment: @the_lotus The most common [collective noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_collective_nouns_in_English) for sheep is 'flock'.

Answer (score 3):

I think I'd append a word indicating what it is:

```
var sheepList = new List<Sheep>();
// Adding objects to the collection

foreach (var sheepItem in sheepList)
{
    // Do something with the current sheepItem
}
```

I'd avoid [Hungarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation)-style prefixes or suffixes (like `mSheep` for "multiple" or `iSheep` for "item", or `sheepS` for "single" - especially that last one, since it's too easy to confuse with `sheeps`) due to clarity. And trying to invent a way to pluralize it (`sheeps` for the plural) would just be confusing.

Comment: Yes that also bugs me, I don't like Hungarian-style either. But explicitly adding List to sheep could be confusing when you have an array or a `HashSet` instead of a `List`

Comment: @AndreasAdler I might use `Collection`, `Set`, or `Items` as the suffix, depending on the type. In general, I'd say you could make it match whatever type you declare it as (not necessarily the implementation), e.g. `ICollection<Sheep> sheepCollection = new HashSet<Sheep>();`

Comment: Wouldn't it be sort of Hungarian Notation if you'd use different suffixes for different collection types?

Comment: @AndreasAdler hm, I think of Hungarian Notation as using *abbreviated prefixes* to show the types, while using *full suffixes* is something different. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifier_naming_convention#.NET), the .NET conventions support this view, and aren't against using them.

Answer (score 0):

sheep - sheepS is hard to read for me.

i prefer mSheepS where m stands for multiple.  With double s's it looks kind of funny but take "horse" for example;

int horse
int horseS
int mHorseS

and of course best way to do it is

int manyHorses

depending on your code and how many times you will use manyHorses you may change between but I highly recommend manyHorses, manySheeps etc

Comment: Both the "m" prefix and the capital "S" go against Microsoft's .Net naming conventions.

Comment: Actually the "m" prefix bugs me more than my current "S" suffix.